# mysql append to first row, move other rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a microcontroller currently sending data to a mysql database, and it is working fine using `mysqli_insert(X,X)`. The problem is that this method appends to the end.

Is there a way I can have mysql append to the first row instead of the last row?

For example if my current mysql table has 10 rows, rows 1-10, the new data would be inserted to row 1 and the 10 other rows would be push to rows 2-11. is this something that is possible? I am not new to programming but I am new to MySQL thanks all!

Comment: why should that matter?

Comment: Is not should be an issue, Each row have a unique number that generated automatically. you don't what to change it

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets, so there is no "first" row in a table.  The question doesn't really make sense without context.

Comment: Welcome to posting on Stack Overflow! Please supply the data that @GordonLinoff has requested and check these guidelines for creating good posts: [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Cheers!

Comment: gordon, so my data is the [ID,LOGTIME,TEMPERATURE,HUMIDITY] the reason I need it this way, is because I have already created a website that grabs data in real-time and graphs it, the problem is the graph takes the first 10 values which are old values and the new values are appended to the end.

Comment: Also, I tried to organize the table using SELECT * from Weatherdata ORDER BY time DESC but that did not work.. is there another way to organize the table by time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql tables are not ordered by default. Generally a simple query to a table could return the rows in the order that were created, but this is not a contract. You must not rely on that.

The better way to ensure you get the rows in a certain order is to assing a **key row** as **auto-incremental** (this could be done only when you create the table in mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    amount int,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

After that you can insert rows without using the autoincremental field (is automatic)

```
INSERT INTO mytable ( name, amount) VALUES ('John', 23);
```

Then, you can select the fields in the order that were created using

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id;
```

And select the fields in the reverse order of creation using a descendant order:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Additionally, if you want to pick only **the last N rows** you can use the LIMIT clause:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10;
```

But if you need to get the **last N rows in the order of creation** you need a nested query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
) t ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: Thanks the problem was actually my website code not the mysql code, I got it fixed yours put in the most effort so I accepted yours, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just to complement the other answer and make the point really clear.

There's no such thing as the *order of the table rows* in a SQL database like MySQL. This is part of the SQL specification that gives freedom to the database engine to [internally] massage the data all it wants in order to keep it safe and produce fast queries. In simple words: "a SQL database is not an Excel sheet."

If you want to **retrieve** the data in a specific order, just specify the preferred order using `ORDER BY` in your `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Thanks the problem was actually my website code not the MySQL code, I was doing ORDER BY already in the MySQL query but my php code with overriding it which is why it didn't work. thanks for taking the time to answer appreciated!